# setting lower_bound in stl set

Tags: c++, stl, set

I want to set the lower_bound and upper_bound for a multiset of structs to iterate through a range. How do I set it correctly for strings?

```
#include ...
...    
struct foo{
    int bar;
    string test;
};

struct comp{
    inline bool operator()(const foo& left,const foo& right){
        return strcasecmp(left.test.c_str(), right.test.c_str());
    }
};

int main(){
    std::multiset<foo,comp> fooset;
    std::multiset<foo,comp>::iterator it, itLow;

    ...//insert into fooset

    //how do set lower_bound to element where string is "aab" or whatever?

    return 0;
}
```

How can I set itLow to point to the element with string test starting with "ab"?

I tried:

```
itLow = fooset.lower_bound("string");
```

I know that's not sufficient...but I'm not sure how to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct a `foo` from the string, then use `lower_bound` (or `upper_bound`, as he case may be) to search for the position:

```
struct foo {
    int bar;
    string test;

    foo(string i) : test(i) {}
};

std::multiset<foo, comp> fooset;

std:multiset<foo,comp>::iterator it = 
    std::lower_bound(fooset.begin(), fooset.end(), foo("string"), comp());
```

Comment: Its a constructor for `foo` that lets you pass in a string, which gets used to initialize `test`.

Comment: I'm getting an "instantiated from here" error for the last line, when i try to test this out.

Also...when I change 'lower_bound' to 'upper_bound', I get a unable to resolve error. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @JayKim: Oops -- when you specify the comparison function instead of using `operator<`, you also have to pass it to `lower_bound`, like `std::multiset<foo, comp>::iterator it = std::lower_bound(fooset.begin(), fooset.end(), foo("string"), comp());`